# EOF encountered when reading data in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to read an initial data file into my fortran 90 program using:

> !---- Open Initial Data File ----
>     open(50,file=FILE_INITIAL)
>
> !---- Read Status ----
>     read(50,'(a3)') tmp3

I get the following error on the attempt to read the first line:

> Fortran runtime error: End of file

I can correct this with a 'end=' statement, but then I can't read the following lines of data.

Note that this code has worked well on a different server, but another server I am trying to run it on it is not working.

File contents are as follows:

> CNT$
>    0.0000000E+00$
>    105000$
>    1 1  0.6000000E+19  0.2302255E+06 -0.8082365E+06 -0.1359744E+07 -0.1569188E+03  0.1889497E+03  0.1642805E+01  0.1185276E+06  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.1317501E+07$
>         2 1  0.6000000E+19  0.4091322E+06 -0.7740022E+06 -0.1390028E+07 -0.1547697E+03  0.1907412E+03  0.1055918E+01  0.1165642E+06  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.1320302E+07$
>         3 1  0.6000000E+19  0.5670843E+06 -0.7934081E+06 -0.1364818E+07 -0.1560887E+03  0.1897379E+03  0.1457756E+01  0.1170522E+06  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.1214425E+07$

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: I show the input file above now. There are two more read statements similar to the first one, and then a loop for the bulk data. But the program fails at the first line. What is shown is pasted from vim :set list.

Comment: Are the two computers the same OS?   Are you sure that your are opening the correct file?

Comment: Are those dollar signs part of the file content or are they just markers for the end of each line?

Comment: The dollar signs are just markers for the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you report suggest to me that the file you are trying to open does not exist, despite your conviction that it does.  Check that you have got the name and location of the file correct.  Look in the program's working directory to see if a file of the name you are trying to open has been created with size 0 -- Fortran will usually 'helpfully' create an empty file when you try to open one that doesn't exist.

If this guess is wrong, try using the INQUIRE routine to figure things out, maybe experiment with STATUS and some of the other arguments to OPEN.

Comment: When the file doesn't exist I get a different error. Also, if I add an end=550 argument to open and 550 continue statement after, the program can read the first line of the input file (but gives an error on the second read statement, which isn't shown).

Comment: Most output from inquire seems normal: sequential, formatted, little endian, direct. But RECL = -1. Strange?

Answer (score 0):

If the 1D array that should fit the record is longer than the record, it will be filled with subsequent records until the end of the file. My guess is that you have a really long array to put that stuff in. You need to specify `eor=450` to stop at the end of the record and at 450 you read the next line, for example. If you do this, be sure to first fill the array with some thing else, like 0 or -1, so that you don't have random data in the unwritten entries of the array.

Comment: He seems to have problems reading the first line already. That's why he reads with `a3` a character of length three. There is no reading of any array shiwn in the OP's code.

Comment: That is true @VladimirF, and i didn't read look carefulle enough.  It could be a misstake though. For example doing `character tmp3(100)` instead of `character(100) tmp3` would give an array, and this behavior would materialize if the file is shorter than 100 values in total.